# Conditional count of Dummy Variables in R

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this

```
> data
         Date Dummy
1  2020-01-01     1
2  2020-01-02     0
3  2020-01-03     0
4  2020-01-04     0
5  2020-01-05     1
6  2020-01-06     1
7  2020-01-07     1
8  2020-01-08     0
9  2020-01-09     1
10 2020-01-10     1
11 2020-01-11     0
```

I want to create a new column which gives the cumulative frequency of dummy values but conditional on whether the dummy was present or not. The final data set looks like this

```
> data
         Date Dummy Modified
1  2020-01-01     1        1
2  2020-01-02     0        1
3  2020-01-03     0        1
4  2020-01-04     0        1
5  2020-01-05     1        2
6  2020-01-06     1        3
7  2020-01-07     1        4
8  2020-01-08     0        4
9  2020-01-09     1        5
10 2020-01-10     1        6
11 2020-01-11     0        6
```

How can I acheive this in R. Preferably dplyr . Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Take a look at `?cumsum`

Comment: Yes. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

We can just do a `cumsum`

```
cumsum(data$Dummy)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 6
```

This can be implemented within the `%>%` chain

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(Modified = cumsum(Dummy))
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the tip